# how declare local variable in vb.net with largescope

Tags: scope

example:
class start
sub one
dim n as integer=5+2
end sub

sub tow
msgbox(n )
end sub
end class
I want to declare a variable in a sub and use it from another sub ...or its scope is for class but declares it in a sub.
thanks.

Comment: example: 

class start 
     sub one 
          dim n as integer=5+2 
     end sub

     sub tow 
          msgbox(n ) 
     end sub 
end class 

I want to declare a variable in a sub and use it from another sub ...
 or its scope is for class but declares it in a sub.

 thanks.